# CSS 2-column layout for responsive layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am sure there is an answer to this somewhere, but I have looked around for awhile and I must not be searching the right terms. This is really two questions but they might be related.

I have 2 sections to the page, where there could be any number of "info sections" and one "other section." For responsive design they must appear like so (and as such are ordered in my HTML accordingly):

```
|info div |
-----------
|info div |
-----------
|info div |
-----------
|other div|
```

But for my full-size site I would like to have something like this, where the info divs are on the right-hand side until the end of the other div, and then take up 100% of the width:

```
| other div            |  info div  |
| (other div content)  |  (content) |
|                      |  info div  |
|  (end of content)    |  (content) |
-----------------------             |
|<------info div (content) -------->|
```

I can get this working using float: left for the div, but not without putting the info DIVs after the "other div." Also, I'd like to line-break an entire section rather than the line itself, so as to avoid something like this:

```
| other div            |  info div  |
| (other div content)  |  (content) |
|                      |  info div  |
|  (end of content)    |  (content) |
-----------------------   info div  |
|<---------------(content) -------->|
```

Thanks for any help, I can provide more details or examples if needed. Here is a page on the site that demonstrates my issue:

http://collections.centerofthewest.org/treasures/view/cap_sioux_northern_plains_plastic_billed_beads_seed_nylon_geometr

Above 1000px or so it looks right, except I'd like the entire "block" to be pushed to the next line instead of a single line. Below 1000px, you'll see the content is stacked, but not in the order I'd like (Related Articles and Virtual Galleries should be above).

Thanks.

Comment: Please show your code effort

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried the bootstrap library?  They have a 12-column grid system that should do what you want. [Here's a link!](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: It took me some time to get back to this, but actually this is just what I needed. Thanks.